# Flag Text is showing link instead of creating link

Tags: bug, status-completed, close-dialog, flag-dialog

I went to flag a question as off topic. When I've selected `it should be closed for another reason...`, the link in the `off-topic because...` option isn't displaying properly.

[image: Link Error]

Comment: Same here. I am able to replicate this on Meta/SO.

Comment: I was just about to report this, good to see someone else already did :)

Comment: Same in the close dialog.

Comment: not again... fixing :)

Comment: @m0sa let me guess: new caching mechanism on localized pages? ;)

Comment: Edge cases within edge cases, wheels within wheels, a fix is rolling out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fix for this went out with the latest deploy.

Off-topic is a tad odd since the moderators can edit sub reasons.  Missed an early return when converting some code, and accidentally double encoded that description.